# Detecting JavaScript errors in a UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can my iPhone Objective-C code get notified of Javascript errors in a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193119/how-can-my-iphone-objective-c-code-get-notified-of-javascript-errors-in-a-uiwebv)

I'm running into a very annoying issue developing javascript for a `UIWebView` in an iPhone application.  If there is an error in the javascript, it silently fails and halts execution of the function it was running.  And some errors do not happen in a desktop browser, so all appears fine.  I then run it on an iPhone and get a massive failure as the function craps out half way through, and no idea why.  I then slowly and methodically comment out various lines of code until no catastrophic failures happen, in order to pinpoint the offending line of code.

This sucks.

So is there any way at all to get a `UIWebView` to log or report in anyway javascript errors?  They are obviously happening, I just don't know why or how, and it's making my life hard.