# Javascript console.log() in an iOS UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

When writing a iPhone / iPad app with a UIWebView, the console isn't visible.
[this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193119/how-can-my-iphone-objective-c-code-get-notified-of-javascript-errors-in-a-uiwebvi) shows how to trap errors, but I would like to use the console.log() as well.

Comment: Write it in the browser first, turn on Developer Tools, then look at the console output.

Comment: There's a lot of options presented in this similar question: *[Debug iPad Safari with a PC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20408110/195835)* - these don't require any native code to use.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I have a solution to log, using javascript, to the apps debug console.
It's a bit crude, but it works.

First, we define the console.log() function in javascript, which opens and immediately removes an iframe with a ios-log: url.

```
// Debug
console = new Object();
console.log = function(log) {
  var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
  iframe.setAttribute("src", "ios-log:#iOS#" + log);
  document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
  iframe = null;    
};
console.debug = console.log;
console.info = console.log;
console.warn = console.log;
console.error = console.log;
```

Now we have to catch this URL in the UIWebViewDelegate in the iOS app using the shouldStartLoadWithRequest function.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView2 
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSString *requestString = [[[request URL] absoluteString] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(requestString);

    if ([requestString hasPrefix:@"ios-log:"]) {
        NSString* logString = [[requestString componentsSeparatedByString:@":#iOS#"] objectAtIndex:1];
                               NSLog(@"UIWebView console: %@", logString);
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: see the simple idea of NSTJ below.

Comment: in swift 4 maybe? :D

Answer (score 201):

After consulting with an esteemed colleague today he alerted me to the Safari Developer Toolkit, and how this can be connected to UIWebViews in the iOS Simulator for console output (and debugging!).

Steps:

1. Open Safari Preferences -> "Advanced" tab -> enable checkbox "Show Develop menu in menu bar"
2. Start app with UIWebView in iOS Simulator
3. Safari -> Develop -> i(Pad/Pod) Simulator -> `[the name of your UIWebView file]`

You can now drop complex (in my case, *flot*) Javascript and other stuff into UIWebViews and debug at will.

EDIT: As pointed out by @Joshua J McKinnon this strategy also works when debugging UIWebViews on a device.  Simply enable Web Inspector on your device settings: Settings->Safari->Advanced->Web Inspector (cheers @Jeremy Wiebe)

UPDATE: WKWebView is supported too

Comment: Note, this strategy also works when debugging on real iOS devices.

Comment: +100 if I could.  This is wonderful, it works for phone gap apps too!

Comment: This should be made the answer. This is wonderful and I agree with the above, this should get all the up votes

Comment: Can anyone tell me please how can it be done with iOS devices?

Comment: @Floydian what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Trying with an iPad, when I go to the develop menu on Safari, there are no Devices to choose. When I deploy on the simulator, it works like a charm.

Comment: @Floydian you have to enable Web Inspector on the device.  Settings->Safari->Advanced->Web Inspector.

Comment: Whenever I set a breakpoint in a JS file this way, the debugger breaks there, but then the step buttons don't work.  They don't respond to clicks.  has anyone else seen this?

Comment: my app is not showing up in my develop menu. I have enabled web inspector. Safari shows up, but my app (which is current;y displaying 2 UIWebviews) is not detected.. any ideas?

Comment: Don't miss out on @Floydian comment: you need to enable Web Inspector on the device as well.

Comment: Any way to get this to work in the simulator? I don't have i(Pad/Pod) Simulator in my Develop menu in Safari.

Comment: @Curtis it should definitely work in the Simulator+Safari - are you still having the issue?

Comment: Yes I have Xcode 10.1, and when I run my app in the simulator and go to Safari and click Develop, there is no Simulator option. If I run on my iPhone, it does show that iPhone in the Develop menu.

Comment: @Curtis I had that issue too. It's working for me now. It's strange but I have to open a new instance of safari and also close the simulator and run the app again

Answer (score 37):

**Here's the Swift solution:**
*(It's a bit of a hack to get the context)*

1. You create the UIWebView.
2. Get the internal context and override the ***console.log()*** javascript function.

   ```
   self.webView = UIWebView()
   self.webView.delegate = self

   let context = self.webView.valueForKeyPath("documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext") as! JSContext

   let logFunction : @convention(block) (String) -> Void =
   {
       (msg: String) in

       NSLog("Console: %@", msg)
   }
   context.objectForKeyedSubscript("console").setObject(unsafeBitCast(logFunction, AnyObject.self), 
                                                        forKeyedSubscript: "log")
   ```

Comment: +100! saved me TONS of time, great hack, requires 0 changes in JS code. Thanks!! Just my 2 cents for future readers: don't forget to link `JavaScriptCore` framework to your project and `import` it in your webview swift file.

Comment: Works for me with Swift 4... you haveto cast "log" to NSString..context.objectForKeyedSubscript("console").setObject(unsafeBitCast(logFunction, to: AnyObject.self),
                                                             forKeyedSubscript: "log" as NSString)

Answer (score 28):

Starting from iOS7, you can use native Javascript bridge. Something as simple as following

```
 #import <JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore.h>

JSContext *ctx = [webview valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
ctx[@"console"][@"log"] = ^(JSValue * msg) {
NSLog(@"JavaScript %@ log message: %@", [JSContext currentContext], msg);
    };
```

Comment: Out of interest, where is the ideal place to put this code?

Comment: OK, figured it out. Just after you created the `UIWebview` you can setup any `JSContext` stuff.

Comment: Does `JSContext` still work in iOS 8+ with `WKWebView`?

Comment: I put it into `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` and it works perfectly!

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze: I tried with `WKWebView` and iOS 11.4.1 and he can't find `documentView` and crashes. I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792131/how-to-get-jscontext-from-wkwebview) and it seems that, it isn't possible this way.

Answer (score 9):

NativeBridge is very helpful for communicating from a UIWebView to Objective-C.  You can use it to pass console logs and call Objective-C functions.

https://github.com/ochameau/NativeBridge

```
console = new Object();
console.log = function(log) {
    NativeBridge.call("logToConsole", [log]);
};
console.debug = console.log;
console.info = console.log;
console.warn = console.log;
console.error = console.log;

window.onerror = function(error, url, line) {
    console.log('ERROR: '+error+' URL:'+url+' L:'+line);
};
```

The advantage of this technique is that things like newlines in log messages are preserved.

Comment: +1. Note to [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) users - Cordova already handles `console.log`, but the `window.onerror` function in this answer is very useful!

Comment: For Appcelerator/Titanium developers: this too works to debug your Ti.UI.WebView

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
      webView.evaluateJavaScript("your javascript string") { (value, error) in
          if let errorMessage = (error! as NSError).userInfo["WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage"] as? String {
                print(errorMessage)
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: where to put this code?

Answer (score 0):

Tried Leslie Godwin's fix but was getting this error:

```
'objectForKeyedSubscript' is unavailable: use subscripting
```

For Swift 2.2, here's what worked for me:

You will need to import JavaScriptCore for this code to compile:

```
import JavaScriptCore

if let context = webView.valueForKeyPath("documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext") {
    context.evaluateScript("var console = { log: function(message) { _consoleLog(message) } }")
    let consoleLog: @convention(block) String -> Void = { message in
        print("javascript_log: " + message)
    }
    context.setObject(unsafeBitCast(consoleLog, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "_consoleLog")
}
```

Then in your javascript code, calling console.log("_your_log_") will print in Xcode console.

Better yet, add this code as an extension to UIWebView:

```
import JavaScriptCore

extension UIWebView {
    public func hijackConsoleLog() {
        if let context = valueForKeyPath("documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext") {
            context.evaluateScript("var console = { log: function(message) { _consoleLog(message) } }")
            let consoleLog: @convention(block) String -> Void = { message in
                print("javascript_log: " + message)
            }
            context.setObject(unsafeBitCast(consoleLog, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "_consoleLog")
        }
    }
}
```

And then call this method during your UIWebView initialization step:

```
let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectZero)
webView.hijackConsoleLog()
```