# See Phonegap's console log in iOS devices

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, cordova

I'm writing a PhoneGap application, and it's already works on Android, but on iPhone something fails.
What's even more unfortunate is I can't see the console.log outputs to see what's wrong.
I can do alerts, but that's not sufficient as I can't catch the errors.

Under Android I see everything under the LogCat window. Is there anything similar in iPhone/ios?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the xcode console when the phone is plugged in

Comment: Yeah, the xcode console has nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For web development on mobile I use [Weinre](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre) for debugging. It redirects console.log to a remote debugging window, and should work with Phonegap.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've tried Weinre, and it does show the DOM, but the console tab is always empty.

Comment: Well, the console allows to run commands, so it did help me solve the current problem, but I would still love to be able to see all console messages.

Answer (score 4):

JSConsole: http://jsconsole.com/

It's the best for this purpose, I've used it with iOS & Android PhoneGap / Cordova apps with success. You execute JavaScript commands from your browser remotely on the device and also see console output. No plugins required. It's just a matter of an extra <script> tag. Just make sure to take it out before releasing to the App Store / Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

I've previously written [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508313/javascript-console-log-in-an-ios-uiwebview) answer to enable console.log logging to the xCode console in generic iOS UIWebViews.

This approach works in phonegap as well:

- Uncomment the 'shouldStartLoadWithRequest' function in MainViewController.m in
- Follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508313/javascript-console-log-in-an-ios-uiwebview) instructions.

Comment: Actually, turns out Cordova (at least 2.3.0 in my case) does console logging by default. Every console.log after the 'deviceready' event fires is logged. These hacks shouldn't be necessary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Safari (not Xcode)

Instructions: http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html

It works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6eB5TWx0vk

---

Maybe you are missing plugin? See this: [console.log not working in an iOS PhoneGap 3.0 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183295/console-log-not-working-in-an-ios-phonegap-3-0-app)

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-console.git
```