# A way to skip crash on iOS (iPhone, iPad)

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

It may be a newb questions, but still.

I'm working on iOS 6 application for iPhone and iPad, and i'm working on hybrid application Javascript\UIWebView + Objective C

The problem is that i have an internal exception in Private framework. **This exception is caused by something that is inside a Javascript\UIWebView**. And i don't know what Javascript code causing an exception.

So i wan't to do this:

1) Somehow "skip\shallow" crash

2) Using remote Safari debugger, get some info from application

So my question is, is there a way to "skip\shallow" crash, to make my application work for at least few seconds.

Comment: is it a crash, or the app is killed due to memory usage?

Comment: no it's crash, i cheked memory usage - it's about 30mb (stable) no matter how long i work with app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your only chance to deal with this is by placing log traces all over your javascript, so you can track down where the crash is happening.

To do this, you might find useful [this S.O. post showing how you can have JS log to your Xcode console.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508313/javascript-console-log-in-an-ios-uiwebview)