# UIwebView's shouldStartLoadWithRequest: delegate method Does not Receive all Load Requests

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm using UIWebView's shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: delegate method to intercept html links that are executed in a web page. I am doing this so that I can receive realtime notifications from the web page. However, I'm executing about 5 web page loads in quick succession to try to receive data being passed by a custom URL scheme. I'm simply trying to log them all right now so my code looks like this:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"Received Request: %@", request);
    return NO;

}
```

However all requests are not logged via NSLog. I have confirmed that the Requests are being sent via the OSX Safari web browser's iPhone simulator logs and they do appear there.

Is there a way for me to receive all of these requests via the shouldStartLoadWithRequest: delegate method?

Comment: This is intended behavior. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654468/uiwebviewdelegate-webviewdidfinishload-not-called-during-in-page-navigation/19841287#19841287).

Comment: Thank you for directing me to a question that has helped me Think about this a little differently. However, I'm not sure that it will solve my problem. I am not trying to get webViewDidFinishLoad to be called. I'm trying to get shouldStartLoadWithRequest: to load after every time one of my custom URL schemes is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mention the other answer because it refers to [Native Bridge](https://github.com/ochameau/NativeBridge), which can be used to pass messages between JavaScript and Objective C. Even if that is not your goal, it demonstrates the way to make your calls hit shouldLoad/didFinish methods. The technique is to add a hidden iFrame to the page, load the request in that iFrame, and the request will hit your delegate methods.

Comment: That was it, thank you for directing my attention to that solution specifically. That did solve my problem. Thank you very much!