# Capturing console.log within a UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I'm writing an iOS application with MonoTouch that does some javascript interaction with a UIWebView. For debugging purposes, it would be nice to be able to "capture" `console.log` in the javascript that runs in the UIWebView together with the rest of the application output. Is this possible? Examples using regular Objective-C code is also OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more googling, I came about this answer: [Javascript console.log() in an iOS UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508313/javascript-console-log-in-an-ios-uiwebview)

Converting it to MonoTouch yields this solution:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Json;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace View
{
    public class JsBridgeWebView : UIWebView
    {

        public object BridgeDelegate {get;set;}

        private const string BRIDGE_JS = @"
            function invokeNative(functionName, args) {
                var iframe = document.createElement('IFRAME');
                iframe.setAttribute('src', 'jsbridge://' + functionName + '#' + JSON.stringify(args));
                document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
                iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
                iframe = null;  
            }

            var console = {
                log: function(msg) {
                    invokeNative('Log', [msg]);
                }
            };  
        ";

        public JsBridgeWebView ()
        {
            ShouldStartLoad += LoadHandler;
            LoadFinished += (sender, e) => {
                EvaluateJavascript(BRIDGE_JS);
            };
        }

        public bool LoadHandler (UIWebView webView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType)
        {
            var url = request.Url;
            if(url.Scheme.Equals("jsbridge")) {
                var func = url.Host;
                if(func.Equals("Log")) {
                    // console.log
                    var args = JsonObject.Parse(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url.Fragment));
                    var msg = (string)args[0];
                    Console.WriteLine(msg);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Now all `console.log` statements in javascript in a `UIWebView` will be sent to `Console.WriteLine`. This could of course be extended to any kind of output one would want.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add javascript code that does something like this to overwrite the method:

```
console.log = function(var text) {
    consoleforios += text;
}
```

Then from the web view, call:

```
string console = webView.EvaluatingJavaScript("return consoleforios;");
```

This might not be something I'd leave in permanently, but it should work.

Comment: That is an option, but not quite what I was looking for.