# WKWebView interacting with JS in swift3 crashed strangely

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I have a viewController in which I created a WKWebView, here is one of the delegate methods:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    let model = SwiftJSModel()

    self.jsContext = webView.value(forKeyPath: "documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext") as! JSContext

    model.jsContext = self.jsContext

    self.jsContext.setObject(model, forKeyedSubscript: "modelObject" as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)

}
```

however, my app will crash after this webView has been loaded, the console shows:

```
reason: '[<WKWebView 0x7fc41d9c7200> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key documentView.'
```

It seems that `webView.value(forKeyPath: "documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext")` doesn't work in swift3, does somebody know why?

Comment: Not the same reason, I created this viewController in code entirely.

Comment: if you comment this code block, did your code works well?

Comment: Yes, it worked well. And if i debug step by step, it will crash when meeting this line ```webView.value(forKeyPath: "documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext") as! JSContext```.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `WKWebView` cannot get the `JSContext`,
 here is where I found it: [How to get JSContext from WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792131/how-to-get-jscontext-from-wkwebview][1])