# How do I repurpose JSContext in UIWebView to WKScriptMessage for WKWebview

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, swift, webkit

I want to convert a UIWebView library to use WkWebview. The remaining piece is switching out JSContext because the `valueForKeyPath` doesn't work anymore. So how do I rewrite something like the following to use WKScriptMessage as the other SO link suggests? (swift or ObjC answer is fine) [How to get JSContext from WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792131/how-to-get-jscontext-from-wkwebview)

```
JSContext *ctx = [webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];


ctx[@"contentPasteCallback"] = ^(JSValue *msg) {
    __weak typeof(weakSelf) StrongSelf = weakSelf;
    StrongSelf.editorPaste = YES;
};

[ctx evaluateScript:@"document.getElementById('zss_editor_content').addEventListener('paste', contentPasteCallback, false);"];
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found the solution？

Comment: Yeah, did you see my answer below? you have to setup listeners in js and then use WKScriptMessageHandler to listen to when they fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. See the PR https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor/pull/243

Basically you inject javascript to start the listeners. The key here is to pass the function which calls webkit using `postMessage` and use the same name, in my case `'jsm'` as what was setup when you create the `WKUserContentController` object

```
    NSString *pasteListener = @"document.getElementById('zss_editor_content').addEventListener('paste', function() {window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsm.postMessage('paste');});";

    [self.editorView evaluateJavaScript:pasteListener completionHandler:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error != NULL) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    }];
```

and then you listen for the response in the `userContentController: didReceiveScript` delegate method from `WKScriptMessageHandler`

```
- (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message {

    NSString *messageString = (NSString *)message.body;
    if ([messageString isEqualToString:@"paste"]) {
        self.editorPaste = YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have converted `UIWebView` to `WKWebView` for Editor. I have created fork from this [Github Link](https://github.com/cjwirth/RichEditorView). The link to my demo can be found [here](https://github.com/DrashtiJaviya-Openxcell/RichEditorView).

Comment: thats awesome! unfortunately doesn't answer my exact problem. The library you forked doesn't seem to have this component so its still not clear to me what the fix is. Also its hard to just use either of these swift libraries because they have code written in swift 3 I don't want to migrate everything to swift 5