# Xcode debugging javascript of a webview in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, webview, xcode-ui-testing

Is it possible to debug a Javascript code(of webview) from Xcode/Swift debug.
Using version xcode 12.

Similar to chrome inspect debugging in webview.

Comment: You can debug from Safari, the Xcode debugger works differently and I don't see how it can connect to the JS code being run.

Comment: and links for help, would be great

Comment: @shrw check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20233054/6791677) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Furthermore you can even write a test for it. Suppose that you have a Webview which in textbox written by javascript codes then you need to find location of items with coordinates. Finally you can test it like this;

```
let textFieldVector = CGVector(dx: 247, dy: 436)
let textFieldCoordinate = app.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: .zero).withOffset(textFieldVector)
textFieldCoordinate.tap()
app.typeText("your Login username")
```

Also my medium article can be useful if you proceed test cases for Webviews . Link is [here](https://seyitcodeit.medium.com/xcode-ui-tests-for-salesforce-facebook-and-twitter-login-screens-in-wkwebview-2d1c829972bb).

Comment: need a debugger like chrome inspect for webview .. don't know how this helps