# UIWebView acting differently than Safari app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm working on an iOS app with an `UIWebView`. The webpage displayed in the `UIWebView` is working fine when displayed in the Safari app on iOS, but when it is displayed inside an `UIWebView` nothing happens when tapping the "Sign in" button: http://www.bnpsolutions.com/Common/Login_Mobile.aspx.

Does someone know why?

You can download my small iOS example project here:
http://uploads.demaweb.dk/WebView.zip

**EDIT1:**

I've changed the WebView to display [a simple page which just including jQuery](http://uploads.demaweb.dk/jquery.html): http://uploads.demaweb.dk/WebView2.zip.

The error message is:

```
WebView[13623:11703] JavaScript exception: (/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js):5187 - SYNTAX_ERR - SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12
Line:
(function(){
```

Why are the UIWebView not able to load jQuery?

Comment: Well, i just test it... And it's working fine: username 'hi', password 'none' -> security error

Comment: I've rechecked and it's failing "sometimes".. Weird

Comment: Have you tested it in an `UIWebView`?

Comment: Yes, in an `UIWebView` (it fails) and in the iOS Simulator. It seems a javascript problem.

Comment: How can I debug JS in the UIWebView? I've been searching for this, but it seems that the resources I found does not work for iOS 5.

Comment: This question help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193119/how-can-my-iphone-objective-c-code-get-notified-of-javascript-errors-in-a-uiwebv/193282#193282.

Comment: Can you post the html/javascript for the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, using this [code](http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-ios.git;a=commit;h=5d2e8049) to debug your UIWebView i found 2 exceptions in your javascript related to the resource `/WebResource.axd`. Check that and I hope it result useful.

Comment: Could you please share your sample project with me?

Comment: @DennisMadsen Humm i just test it, and if jquery is in local, it works, but remotely doesn't

Comment: Can you tell me, why this does not work? My client does have a page using jQuery and I need to view that page in my *UIWebView*.

Comment: @DennisMadsen I sorry Dennis, I'm lost with this :(

Comment: I've just updated the jQuery test-page. It seems that jQuery loads anyways, since it is able to write jQuery version. I guess jQuery is loaded on my clients site as well. Back to the original question -- I'm still wondering, why nothing happens when tapping the "sign in" button.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest defining the delegate methods:

```
– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
– webViewDidStartLoad:
– webViewDidFinishLoad:
– webView:didFailLoadWithError:    /* especially this one!! */
```

and put some NSLog traces there so that you can see what is happening. It is possible that Safari is more resilient to errors (or handles it in a friendlier way) than UIWebView, hence the difference in behavior. But you should check it directly in your app...

Comment: I've already done that in my original project. The `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` delegate method is never called.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the error message generated - the UIWebView is indeed able to load jQuery - the message you're getting about the exception (based on the link in the comments about how debugging the UIWebView is hooked up) occurs when the exception is raised - whether the exception is caught or not.

That particular function in jQuery has a try/catch near the beginning of the function that purposefully tries to raise an exception (and catch it).

Try this code to see what I mean:

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<html><body>Hello World I am a <b>browser</b><script>(function(){try {var a=undefined; a();} catch (err) {} }());</script></body></html>";
[uiWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Whether the try/catch is there or not, the exception will be reported.